# TSQL Delete XML node if its child element contains a given value

Tags: xml, t-sql

XML Storage can have zero or more `<Address>` nodes under `<Addresses>`
Need a query to delete any `<Address>` nodes whose `<AddressLine> = '2 Church Lane'`

Starting XML:

```
declare @t table (storage xml);
insert into @t (storage)
select '<Person>
  <Fullname />
  <Surname>Smith</Surname>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>1 Church Lane</AddressLine>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>2 Church Lane</AddressLine>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>3 Church Lane</AddressLine>
      </Address>
  </Addresses>
</Person>';
```

Resulting XML:

```
<Person>
  <Fullname />
  <Surname>Smith</Surname>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>1 Church Lane</AddressLine>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>3 Church Lane</AddressLine>
      </Address>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it:

```
update @t
SET storage.modify('
    delete (/Person/Addresses/Address[AddressLine = "2 Church Lane"])
')
```