# How to remove an XML node searching by child node value using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I need to delete from the following XML the `Imovel Node` with `CodigoImovel == 6124-2` using Nokogiri Gem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Carga xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Imoveis>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>6124-2</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>86765</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Cobertura</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>981768</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>357468</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>587168</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Comercial/Industrial</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Conjunto</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Comercial/Sala Padrão</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
    </Imoveis>
</Carga>
```

The `XML` code is in the `xml_str` variable and I parsed with this:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
```

This code creates correctly the XML structure with Nokogiri, but I don't know how find by element value and after how to remove it.

Previously I had an ID attribute in the `Imovel` element, like that:

```
<Imovel id="6124-2">......</Imovel>
```

And I am using this to remove:

```
xml.css('#'+imovel_id).remove
```

And it works fine. But the system that will receive this XML does not allow extra attributes in the `Imovel` node.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the question with this code:

```
xml.xpath("//Carga//Imoveis//Imovel[CodigoImovel='"+re_code+"']").remove
```

The [XPATH](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) allows to search in specific node by value. This query returns the specific node. Then the job is to remove the node.

The accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998729/how-to-modify-xml-node-that-contains-a-specific-child-node-value) helped me in the solution.